# Magento cache not getting cleared

Tags: xml, magento, caching, local

I had some configuration issues in my **local.xml**, which I cannot load my magento frontend nor my admin panel, then I fixed the issue I had in my **local.xml**, and to get my new config to be loaded, I deleted everything in **/var/cache** and even whats there in **/var/session** folders. But to my surprise Magento still loads the old local.xml settings.

I tried with restarting apache and cleared my browser cache, nothing works.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Manage to Solve the issue and its the weirdest thing ever. When I change the local.xml to fix the issue I put a backup of the old file saying local_back.xml. I just delete that file and now everything is working fine.
No idea why Magento pick that file up. Any ways issue has been solved.

Note : See comments below for more details, it is the .xml file extension

Comment: Oh crud. I didn't think of that. Magento reads all the **.xml** files it finds and includes them. Always rename them so the file ending is not **.xml** as an example save backup to **local.xml** as **local.xml.sv1**

Comment: This got me with emacs autosave of local.xml. Magento was reading ~local.xml and the db settings we're overriding the new ones in local.xml.

Answer (score 16):

To make changes in core configurations and have them stick (local.xml, base urls, etc.) you need to clear your Magento code cache, often by actually manually deleting the `mage--?` subfolders in `var/cache/`.

Cached configuration can cause all sorts of headaches including having the base urls still pointing back to the original Magento installation (different folders, different server) despite the fact that you can use phpMyAdmin and see that the rows have been updated in the database. Configuration will not be reread from the database until the cached configuration information is deleted.

Another place where stuff gets stuck is in your APC op-code cache if you’re using it. Use the `apc.php` administration page to clear that as well. Stopping and restarting Apache will achieve the same result

And last of all, IF YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSIONS SET PROPERLY ON `var/cache/` AND `var/tmp/` SO THEY’RE BOTH READABLE AND WRITABLE TO YOUR WEB SERVER, Magento may store the cached information in the **system** `/tmp` directory which means that no amount of clearing Magento’s cache will make the cached configs go away until someone reboots the server, the system `/tmp` directory gets cleared and Magento seemingly automagically reads its configs. Or you're told about it and you have access to delete the Magento cache out of `/tmp`. Here's some documentation of this happening in the system temporary storage folder off of root (see images)

**Note:** If you save a backup copy of your `local.xml` file, make sure to rename it to something like `local.xml.sv1` or you will find that Magento still reads it.

[image: Magento Folder in system /tmp]
[image: Magento Cache in system /tmp]

Comment: I dont know why, but I do not have a /tmp in my Magento installation. And as I mentioned in my question I have already deleted all magento--? from /var/cache

Comment: Not magento var/tmp, system /tmp <-- Note it starts with a slash.

Comment: There is no /var/tmp and there is no /system or /system/tmp. and there i no /tmp :(

Comment: Also had this mystifying issue recently with a site where there were base_urls set at the store scope. Kept on clearing cache like a rockhead until finally I went to the next page in the core_config_data table...

Comment: Manual deleting  `rm -rf cache` (deleting the whole folder, not only the content) and not quickly recovering it .. will result in magento storing the files in [root]/tmp  ;)