# changes of db details in local.xml not affecting

Tags: magento, caching, amazon-web-services, configuration, memcached

I recently moved my magento store to Amazon cloud server and database to RDS database server.
I made the necessary changes in local.xml and cleared the var/cache and var/session folder.
But I don't know how the magento is still picking the old database details which I was using on old server.
I think its not picking the details from local.xml but from some other cache stored somewhere else other than var/cache.
I have even tried by renaming and deleting the local.xml file but still result is the same.
Where else could be the configuration cached data be stored ?
Please help.

Comment: Is there another file ending in `...local.xml` in your `app/etc/` directory? This could be overruling your standard local.xml

Comment: All that is required for a file in `app/etc/` to be included in Magento's config is for it to end in `.xml` so any backups you make of `local.xml` must be something like `local.xml.sv1` to avoid loading them. Best to only have `local.xml` and any other subsidary module `.xml` files for things like FPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure there are no **local.xml.extra** or **local.xmlanything** files in **app/etc** directory. (This happened with me sometimes. I had a habit of renaming old local.xml file to local.xml2 and Magento picks that local.xml2 file as a configuration file. So you should delete the old file or move it to some different location.)
2. Make sure the Magento Caching/ Any other caching is disabled. There can be Full Page Cache Extensions installed in your Magento Setup.

Refer this link [Magento cache not getting cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515237/magento-cache-not-get-clear)

Comment: I didn't mean to get advantage of that. I meant to help out someone and appreciate you for that as well.

Comment: Thanks Richard and Harit, moving all files other than local.xml into some other folder helped me. But I wonder why magento picks other files other than local.xml